# Module depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a Jar error when building Cordova App with VS 2017

Tags: android, cordova, azure, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently working on a mobile application with tools for Apache Cordova using Visual Studio 2017. I'm using **Azure mobile app** plugin for this project. When I try to run android project with emulator I'm getting below error.

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Module 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Module 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Execution failed for task ':prepareDebugDependencies'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Dependency Error. See console for details.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Environment:
VS 2017: 15.0
Cordova: 7.1.0
Cordova~android: 6.3.0

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add @aar to the end of your dependency, i.e. ‘com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.3.0@aar' and try it again.

Open the project in Android Studio and add dependencies to build.gradle file, then build .apk completely and see if it helps.